# Spring-kafka: what is the right way to print RecordHeaders?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

Just checked the logs and recognized that `ConsumerRecord` headers printed in absolutely unreadable manner and the reason is that `RecordHeader` holds `value` as `byte[]` as result in the logs I see the following:

> headers = RecordHeaders(headers = [RecordHeader(key = kafka_exception-fqcn, value = [111, 114, 103, 46, 115, 112, 114, 105, 110, 103, 102, 114,  46, 108, 105, 115, 116, 101, 110, 101, 114, 46, 84, 1 100, 69, 120, 99, 101, 112, 116, 105, 111, 110]), RecordHeader(key = kafka_exception-message, value = [76, 105, 115, 116, 101, 110, 101, 114, 32, 102, 97, 105, 108, 101, 100, 59, 32, 105, 115, 32, 111, 114, 115, 112, 114, 105, 110, 103, 102, 114, 97, 109, 101, 119, 111])

Is there a possibility to print instead of `byte[]` human readable `String` representation?

Answer (score 0):

By converting the header values to strings.:

```
public class KafkaConsumer {
    @KafkaListener(topics = "your-topic")
    public void consume(ConsumerRecord<String, String> record) {
        Headers headers = record.headers();

        for (Header header : headers) {
            String key = header.key();
            String value = new String(header.value());
            System.out.println("Key: " + key + ", Value: " + value);
        }

        // Processing
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

To print Kafka message headers in a Spring Kafka consumer using the `@KafkaListener` annotation:

```java
@KafkaListener(
    id = "myKafkaListener",
    groupId = "myConsumerGroup",
    topics = "myTopic",
    autoStartup = "true",
    idIsGroup = false,
    containerFactory = "myContainerFactory"
)
public void consume(@Payload String record, @Header(KafkaHeaders.OFFSET) Long offset,
                   @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_PARTITION_ID) int partition,
                   @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_TOPIC) String topic,
                   @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_TIMESTAMP) long ts,
                   @Headers Map<String, Object> headers) {
    // Print the payload
    System.out.println("Received message: " + record);

    // Print the individual headers
    System.out.println("Offset: " + offset);
    System.out.println("Partition: " + partition);
    System.out.println("Topic: " + topic);
    System.out.println("Timestamp: " + ts);

    // Print all headers
    headers.forEach((key, value) -> {
        System.out.println("Header - " + key + ": " + value);
    });
}
```

In this code:

- `@KafkaListener` is used to configure the listener.
- The method consumes a Kafka message, and it prints the payload, individual headers (such as offset, partition, topic, and timestamp), and all headers using the `@Headers` parameter.

Make sure to replace the sample values (e.g., "myKafkaListener," "myConsumerGroup," "myTopic," and "myContainerFactory") with the actual values you use in your application.